# About emscripten callback functions data pointer

Tags: javascript, c, emscripten

I'm trying to pass a javascript object as a void* through a 'C' library and use it in the callback function;

Basically I have a

```
module.addFunction(function cb(ctx, pos)  {
      ctx.fun(pos);
}
```

I'm passing `ctx` as a '*' in my call using `Module.setValue()`

I'm able to pass the func. pointer using module (it takes a (void*, int) as args)
When the `cb` is called I don't know how to get the object back from ctx.  I've used `getValue()` and that's not helping (log shows it's some number).  How can I cast this void* to the right Javascript object.
If necessary I can post a complete minimal verifiable example.

[edit] Added `C` tag hoping to get some eyes,  I'm a `C` programmer

Comment: Yes, please post mve - I'm having similar question, so would like to see an answer

Comment: Dunno way to "cast" it but you may read basic types and assign. Here I added some very simple example for float array https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65566923/is-there-a-more-efficient-way-to-return-arrays-from-c-to-javascript?noredirect=1#comment116777090_65566923 - conclusion is that you have an access to whole wasm memory also  if you are sending pointer to C and make changes there should not they be visible already at the js side too?