# Is there a more efficient way to return arrays from C++ to javascript?

Tags: javascript, c++, webassembly, emscripten, embind

To pass typed array from emscripten'ed C++ to javascript I came up with this code

```cpp
#include <emscripten/bind.h>
#include <emscripten/val.h>

auto test(const emscripten::val &input) {
  const auto data = emscripten::convertJSArrayToNumberVector<float>(input); // copies data

  // generate output in some form
  std::vector<float> output = { 1, 2, 3 };
  // make a typed array view of the output
  emscripten::val view{ emscripten::typed_memory_view(output.size(), output.data()) };
  // create new typed array to return
  auto result = emscripten::val::global("Float32Array").new_(output.size());
  // copy data from generated output to return object
  result.call<void>("set", view);

  return result;
}

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(KissFft) {
  emscripten::function("test", &test);
}
```

(build with `em++ test.cpp -o test.html --bind`)

In this case there are two extra copies:

- the copy from input array to wasm memory, as far as I understand it's unavoidable;

  ```cpp
  const auto data = emscripten::convertJSArrayToNumberVector<float>(input);
  ```
- the copy from wasm memory to javascript object:

  ```cpp
  emscripten::val view{ emscripten::typed_memory_view(output.size(), output.data()) };
  auto result = emscripten::val::global("Float32Array").new_(output.size());
  result.call<void>("set", view);

  return result;
  ```

**Is there a way to avoid extra copy from generated output to javascript object in the second case?**

I'm aware of the possibility to return memory view like this:

```cpp
std::vector<float> output;

auto test(const emscripten::val &input) {
  const auto data = emscripten::convertJSArrayToNumberVector<float>(input);

  //generate output
  return emscripten::val{ emscripten::typed_memory_view(output.size(), output.data()) };
}

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(KissFft) {
  emscripten::function("test", &test);
}
```

But in this case the returned object refers to the underlying memory owned by `output` static object with all the consequences, like modifying the memory on the C++ side, or even deallocating it.

Comment: JSON.parse/JSON.stringify aren't an option?

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot write into the `Float32Array` directly instead of first creating the local `std::vector`?

Comment: @blanknamefornow, my bet is that copying is faster than JSON parse/stringify.

Comment: @UnholySheep, can you point me towards an example?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot find any examples, but based on the documentation you should be able to index into the array using the `operator[]`. So something like `auto result = emscripten::val::global("Float32Array").new_(3); result[0] = 1.0f;` should work

Comment: Can't you just return a pointer (as number) and then use that pointer as an index to float array (to create a view or copy if needed) e.g. `Module.HEAPF32[pointer >> 2]`? If you are using browser (not WebView) this way you can pass data also between threads/workers.

Comment: @Ryszard Grzesica, that's almost exactly what I ended up doing, see the last snippet in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking to go lower a bit. Putting here (instead of comment) to paste snippets (taken from embind examples from emscripten, here in C but you may do the same with C++).

```
// quick_example.cpp
#include <emscripten/bind.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace emscripten;

struct buffer {
  unsigned int pointer;
  unsigned int size;
};

buffer lerp() {
    buffer myBuffer;
    unsigned int size = 10;

    float * myTab = (float*)malloc(size * sizeof(float));

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      myTab[i] = 2.5 * i;
      printf(" Native side index: %d value: %f address: %p\n", i, myTab[i], &myTab[i]);
    }

    myBuffer.pointer = (unsigned int) myTab; 
    myBuffer.size = size;

    printf(" Native side pointer: %p size: %d\n", myTab, size);
    return myBuffer;
}

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(my_module) {
    value_array<buffer>("buffer")
        .element(&buffer::pointer)
        .element(&buffer::size)
        ;

    function("lerp", &lerp);
}
```

index.html - here in js you may copy, make a view and finally free the memory what (as I understood was one of the problems from above?)

```
   <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <script>
        var Module = {
          onRuntimeInitialized: function() {
            var result =  Module.lerp();
            console.log(" JS side pointer: " + result[0] + " size: " + result[1]);
     
            for (var i = 0; i < result[1]; i++) {
              console.log("index: " + i + " value: " + Module.HEAPF32[(result[0] + i * 4) / 4] + " pointerInc: " + (result[0] + i * 4));
            }
    
            Module._free(result[0]);
          }
        };
      </script>
      <script src="lerp.js"></script>
    </html>
```

build command

```
emcc --bind -o lerp.js lerp.cpp
```

Comment: That's basically what I ended up doing, see the last snippet in the question. As far as I understand it, there is no other way of doing it right now. Probably we will be able to do something different when 'anyref' is added to the specification.